# Water Flowing In And Out Of A Basin

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

After a tap above a rectangular basin has been turned on, the basin fills in a time T1. After the tap is closed, opening a hole at the bottom of the basin causes the basin to empty in a time T2.

1. If both are open at the same time, what is the time taken for the basin to empty?
2. What ratio of T1/T2 can cause the basin to overflow?

I can tell the rate of water flowing in is a constant due to a tap. But I don't think the water flowing is out is constant and I am not sure how to set up the differential equation such that I can get the answer.

Comment: Do you have any extra data on the problem? As such, it is not solvable without further hypothesis.

Comment: Nope that is the full problem as posted to me

Comment: Then I guess you have to assume outflow is constant,

Answer (score 0):

(If water flowing out is constant)
Considering draining of water to be constant,
Let the volume of basin be ***V***.
Therefore the Taps rate of filling water is,
$$
Say,\space M=V/T_1,
$$
and hole's rate of draining is,
$$
Say,\space N=V/T_2,
$$
Lets say the water is filled fully at a rate of ***M*** in ***T1***, therefore at a rate of ***M - N*** in ***T1*** time how much water is filled?,
$$
M\space\space\space V
$$
$$
M-N\space\space\space\space\space\space x
$$
$$
x=V(M-N)/M,\space in\space T_1, 
$$
if at a rate of ***M - N*** only ***V(M-N)/M*** volume is filled then time taken to fill whole is,
$$
T=MVT_1/V(M-N)=T_1T_2/(T_2-T_1),
$$

Comment: I do not think the water flowing out is constant as it would be a function of the hydrostatic pressure

Comment: @user215379 Then sufficient data must be given.